# Behaviour of emails sent with "Surpress from reports" in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

When this option is selected, how can we track scheduled sends? and is the send tracking still available in Data Views (i.e. Sent table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 'Suppress from Reports" will prevent the tracking data from being displayed inside the 'tracking' tab of the SFMC UI, but the job information will still be inside the dataviews.

For opens, you will need to ensure you added in the tracking pixel in your email, and for click you will need to make sure the 'track links' box is checked. With those two items, you will also be able to see the clicks and opens inside of the data views.

For the send log, this will collect as well as long as you do have the 'allow sendlog' box checked on your send.

The 'Suppress from reports' option is mostly centered around the UI tracking features and reports and not the 'back end' stuff like Dataviews or send logs.